# Grow/Shrink css "background-image" with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, joomla, resize, background-image

I have an icon.. I want it to grow on a hover and return to its original size on the mouseout.. I can make the css div do this with:

```
$(".jq_icon").hover(function() {
$(this).stop().animate({width:56, height:56,left:-8,top:-8},'fast');
}, 
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({width:36,height:36,left:8,top:8},'fast');
});
```

, but the actual image does not grow.. How can i achieve with cross browser support..??

Also i am using a CMS (Joomla) And (as far as i know, & correct me if i'm wrong) you cant drop images on the index page using the 'img' tag, it will only display images using 'background-images' via CSS..

Thx in advance !!

Comment: Does the image have to be a background-image? An inline image with width and height of 100% might do the trick.

Comment: hey! Yeah it does, I am using a CMS (joomla) and (as far as i know) you cant drop images on the index page using the <img> tag, it will only display images using 'background-images' via CSS..

Answer (score 0):

you should look at the background-size property but it's not supported yet by jquery as I know.